# Check to see if a dataframe increases to a corner

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a numerous dataframes that looks something like this:

```
| first_column | second_column | third_column |
| ------------ | ------------- | ------------ |
|      25      |        20     |       18     |
|      20      |        21     |       18     |
|      17      |        18     |       16     |
```

I want to see how well they converge to a corner (i.e., how well the values are increasing as you go to a corner of the dataframe). I've tried a couple of different methods, such as using `df.diff() < 0` to see if the values are are decreasing as you go down the column and then converting the `True` or `False` statements to integers of 1 or 0 and summing those up, then doing the same thing but with the dataframe transposed and adding both sums together, but that doesn't seem to give me the correct best dataframes that converge to a corner.

I know this is oddly specific, but is there anyway to best see if the values of a dataframe increase as you go to a corner of the dataframe?

Comment: To any corner? Must the increase/decrease be absolute?

Comment: And also, how do you define "converging", would being the `max` be sufficient?

Comment: Yeah, to any corner. The dataframes are all different in regard to converging to different corners. And the increase/decrease doesn't have to absolute; really, I just want a way to rank the dataframes on how well they converge to the corner!

Comment: Yeah, for converging, basically the max value is in, for example, the top right corner of the dataframe, with *ideally* the next two max values being the cells directly below the top right corner and the one directly next to it.

Comment: That's the thing, can you explicitly describe what "well converging" means? Would a dataframe of all the same values be considered as converging? Which would be most converging among [[2,1],[1,0]] and [[4,2],[2,0]]?

Comment: Can you fit a plane on all the points and calculate the correlation/error?

Comment: Forgot to mention, but none of the dataframes have the same values. I should've mentioned that they are all percentile values, my apologies. And probably the [[2,1],[1,0]] example.

Comment: Didn't think of doing that, but that might be a way to go.